# How to mark certain portion of text in phoneTextBox in Windows phone silverlight 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on windows phone **silverlight** 8.1. I have a [PhoneTextBox](https://phone.codeplex.com/) control to take user input. When user type **@** I provide a list in UserControl. If user select one of them, I replace that typing text with selected Text. I want to change the **selected text color** in PhoneTextBox.

I see [RichEditBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.RichEditBox), may be it does not support in silverlight.

Is it possible to do that or have any workaround?

N.B: User can select multiple item from provided list after typing every **@**

Comment: Syncfusion has a richtextbox for windows phone https://www.syncfusion.com/products/windows-phone/richtexteditor maybe you qualify for their community license